# Is it possible to integrate a Reporting Server (SQL Express 2008 w Advanced Services) in WSS 3 at all?

Tags: sharepoint, ssrs, sql-server-2008

Can I set up the Reporting Server of the Express Edition in some way to work integrated in my sharepoint services site?

I have the reporting-server Add-in on the sharepoint machine and see the itmes in the central administration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SharePoint integrated mode is not supported in SSRS Express Edition. See the feature list on MSDN for details.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc281020.aspx

Comment: Thank you, but I already know that, maybe I should have put that into my initial post. I wanted to know, if there is some kinda workaround.